# Will UITableViewCells be re-used across different instances of UITableViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableView` showing a set of custom `UITableViewCells`. This `tableView` will be instantiated in several different `UIViewControllers`. In some use cases, different `viewControllers` will exist at the same time, in a `UINavigationController`, e.g:

`UIViewController viewA;` pushes to `UIViewController viewB;` Both controllers have their own `UITableView`. Both `tableViews` have their own set of `UITableViewCells` with the same `reuseIdentifier`.

Will it ever happen that a `UITableViewCell` from `viewA` is being reused in `viewB`?

Comment: never tested this but you can check the cell's address in the debugger view.

Comment: same reuseIdentifier? why you're using same identifier for different tables in different view's!

Comment: I guess not, but why does it impact you?

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati Let's take Twitter as an example. One viewController has a tableView showing a list of tweet-tableViewCells. By navigating to a new viewController (e.g by clicking a username), we get another tableView with new tweet-cells. The same xib is used, the same identifier. But will the cells from the first controller (below in the navigation-stack) ever be reused in the new topmost view? Navigation-wise, this can go on forever. You can navigate forever with new instances of a tableView with the same identifier for the cells. It's not a different view, it's a different instance.

Comment: @Wain It would have impacted me because I was thinking of having a new instance of the same tableView(+ cells) in a different class of UIViewController, where the new viewController could e.g change the color of a single UILabel in the cell. If different tableViews would mix and reuse each others cells, I would have to reset the changes I do in the different controller in all views. Now I don't have to think about that.

Comment: You should reset the changes in the cell when it's told it's going to be reused, always.

Comment: @Wain In my very particular case, that would be a total waste. To explain; my plan is to navigate to a cell after user clicks a local notification. One cell, and one cell only. I was thinking of 'highlighting' the part of the cell that corresponds to the information in the notification (e.g some text has been edited, show in red color). This highlight will only happen when navigated by notifications. It would be a waste to "remove hightlight" or "set color back" for EVERY cell in the entire application, when the notification-cell will never be reused anyway. When there's no need, don't.

Comment: However, I do agree with you in general. In fact, there is no need for me to register that particular cell for reuse, as it never will be. My alternative would be to write code in the tableView to check wether or not a cell should be reused(as it is using the same custom tableView). This 'check', even though it's just a single if-statement, would still have to be run for all instances of the tableView. This notification-case is a far less common action, which means this 'check' will be mostly `false`. With the answer I received, it even mans that the check is completely redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/), no.

> A UITableView object maintains a queue (or list) of the currently
>   reusable cells, each with its own reuse identifier, and makes them
>   available to the delegate in the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
>   method

An instance will maintain its own reuse queue.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking there might be a possibility that they share a global 'pool' of reusable cells based on identifiers, but this doc clearly state that they don't.

Answer (score 0):

queueing reuasable cells is per tableView, as

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
   //    instance, not class ⤴︎
```

So a tableView object has it own queue — not the class UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

No. When you create a reused UITableViewCell, a new UITableViewCell linked to its delegate, the UITableView INSTANCE (id):

`- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;`

Therefore, each UITableView will contain another cells list.