# Does each unique reuse identifier have its own unique reuse queue?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitableview, uikit

### Answer

Yes. A unique `reuseIdentifier` corresponds to a unique reuse queue.

According to Apple's documentation for [UITableViewCell's reuseIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623246-reuseidentifier):

> A UITableView object maintains a **queue** (or list) of the currently
>   reusable cells, **each with its own reuse identifier**, and makes them
>   available to the delegate in the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
>   method

Answer was provided by user *Matt* and the source was indirectly linked in a [SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30100374/10830091). The latter was posted by user *prekshya basnet*.

---

### Question's Elaboration

Does each `reuseIdentifier` correspond to a unique reuse queue?

In other words: is it possible to call `register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` with its either implementations [for registering nibs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614937-register) or [for registering classes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register) with different combinations of parameters on the same UITableView instance?  knowing that said combinations of parameters satisfy the following:

- **Identical** [`nib`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614937-register) or [`cellClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register) value in each call, depending on the used implementation for said UITableViewController.
- **Unique** `identifier` for each call

### Question's Trigger

According to [Apple's programming guide: A Closer Look at Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) in *Cells and Table View Performance* section at the very end of the guide, the following guidelines are encouraged:

> 1. Reuse cells.
> 2. Avoid relayout of content.
> 3. Use opaque subviews.

- In order to satisfy the aforementioned guideline items 1. and 2.
- In order to satisfy my requirement that is to have two cells of the same
  type but are are layed out progamatically in a different way even
  though they are the same XIB and UITableView subclass.

Then I need to use two distinct `reuseIdentifier` strings for the same `nib` object.

I can already differentiate between the two `nib` objects, that are layed out differently, in `UITableViewDelegate` or `UITableViewDataSource` using a control flag/enum in the object residing in my `dataSource` backstore collection. This object of course corresponds to the `indexPath` referenced inside the `delegate`/`dataSource`.

### Question's Previous Work

I have scoured the internet using multiple search engines on multiple websites including [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+register+reuse+identifier). I have already checked the following questions: [what registering a call for cell reuse actually do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440046/what-does-registering-a-call-for-cell-reuse-actually-do) and [registered classes for reuse identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337036/collectionview-tableview-registered-classes-for-reuse-identifiers) and many other more that were too distant to even mention.

Comment: The reuse identifier is all that matters. The nib or class can be identical between different reuse identifiers, but if you request a cell with a specific reuse identifier that is what you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does each reuseIdentifier correspond to a unique reuse queue?

Yes. That is exactly what the reuse identifier is: it is the name of one pile of cells available for reuse.

Comment: Knew that only one of you guys would be able to answer this kind of question. Thanks.